# Assigning default value in for loop comprehension along with set intersection

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am trying comprehension logic to assign default vaule for non-standard color and for empty string but I don't know how to achieve this

basically, need to check if required_color is non-standard/pre_defined_color then assign "red" as default.

Is there a better solution without having/checking if conditions in line number 17/18 but somehow handle it in comprehnsion logic itself.

'''

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#testcases:
#a. empty required_color then set "red" as default
#b. if SPECIAL_COLOR then set "green" as default
#c. non-standard color in required_color then set set "red" as default

#required_color variable is comma separated string

required_color = "yellow,orange"
pre_defined_expected_color = "red,blue,green,SPECIAL_COLOR"

#if required_color is empty or non standard color then set required_color to "red" as default
if not required_color or required_color not in pre_defined_expected_color:
    required_color = "red"

for item in set(required_color.split(",")).intersection(set(["red", "blue", "green", "SPECIAL_COLOR"])):
     # if SPECIAL_COLOR color then set item to "green" as default
     if item == "SPECIAL_COLOR":
         item = "green"
     print(item)
     break
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary and get (with default):

```
required_color = "yellow,orange"
pre_defined_expected_color = "red,blue,green,SPECIAL_COLOR"

colorMap = {c:c for c in required_color.split(",")+pre_defined_expected_color.split(",")}

# remap "SPECIAL_COLOR" to "green"
colorMap ["SPECIAL_COLOR"] = "green"

# the .get not really needed here because you only use keys present in dict
for k in colorMap.keys():
    print(colorMap.get(k))

# if your input may contain non-keys use get:

for k in ["pastel","oblique"]:
    print(colorMap.get(k, "green"))
```

Output:

```
yellow
orange
red
blue
green
green   # SPECIAL_COLOR

green   # pastel
green   # oblique
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Will this work if "required_color" is empty string ? I have 3 cases to cover as mentioned in "testcases"

Comment: @HULK - your testcases - try it out